# UITableViewCell's touchesEnded not called when displaying ViewController on top

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a bit of a construction here; I extended a `UITableViewCell` and am displaying a `UIViewController` modally from the `UITableViewController` class when the `touchesBegin` hits in the `UITableViewCell`. When the `touchesEnded` hits, I remove this `UIViewController` again.

So I'm showing something when you touch the cell, and when you release the screen I hide it again. All good, but it doesn't work if I quickly press and release on the UITableViewCell; in this case `touchesEnded` isn't called. If I hold it for a second or longer, the system works fine. 'touchesCancelled' is not called either.

Any thoughts on this? Since the focus is on the `UITableViewCell`, the Touch methods of the newly displayed `UIViewController` or the existing `UITableViewController` won't hit either (until I release and press again, but that defeats the purpose).

The relevant code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    amDisplayingCapture = YES;
    [self.showCaptureDelegate displayCapture:self.capture];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    if( amDisplayingCapture )
    {
        [self.showCaptureDelegate endDisplayCapture];
        amDisplayingCapture = NO;
    }
}
```

(`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of the `UITableView` isn't called either once I present the new `UIViewController`, so can't use that)

Answer (score 3):

From the UIResponder header file:

> Your responder will receive either `touchesEnded:withEvent:` or `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` for each touch it is handling (those touches it received in `touchesBegan:withEvent:`). **You must handle cancelled touches to ensure correct behavior in your application.  Failure to do so is very likely to lead to incorrect behavior or crashes.**

Summary: you should also implement `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`.

Comment: There's more information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks, but I should've mentioned touchesCancelled isn't called either. Not in the UITableViewCell where I expected it, and not in the other ViewControllers. 

It's like the touchesBegan is called but then disappears without a trace.

Comment: All touches should be ended or cancelled. Is it possible you have a subview that overrides these methods also?

Comment: If not, you should create a sample project that demonstrates the behavior, and submit it with a bug report to Apple.

Comment: I've gone through the subviews and put all touches-delegate methods in, none are called. I was expecting it to trigger in touchesCancelled too. If I can't figure it out, I'll do as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

In the event someone has a similar situation, I resolved this by adding the new viewcontroller's view as a subview rather than presenting the entire viewcontroller modally. That seemed to allow the touchesEnded to be called.